# PHP Call mysql stored procedure with in parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I'm calling a mysql stored procedure with two input parameters. This is the code I have:

```
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
    if (!$con) {     
        echo '<b>Could not connect.</b>';
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    } else {          
        mysql_select_db("php_database_1", $con);

        $username_v = $_POST['username'];
        $password_v = $_POST['password'];

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL login(?, ?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $username_v, $password_v, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

        // call the stored procedure
        $stmt->execute();

        print "procedure returned $username_v\n";
```

When executing, I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in E:\xampp\htdocs\php4\default.php on line 52
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\php4\default.php on line 52

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Either you have not created any DB connection file/Class or if you created you don't include it?

Comment: i created a connection to the database. See my post i have edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited**: After seeing more code, you have attempted to mix the `mysql_()` functions with PDO.  You cannot do that -- instead, use PDO only. The two APIs do not work together, and the old `mysql_*()` API does not support prepared statements at all.

You have not connected to your database or instantiated a PDO object.

```
$username_v = $_POST['username'];
$password_v = $_POST['password'];
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';

// You must first connect to the database by instantiating a PDO object
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root_db_pw');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Then you can prepare a statement and execute it.    
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL login(?, ?)");
// One bindParam() call per parameter
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username_v, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(2, $password_v, PDO::PARAM_STR); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. I executed your code, but i get this error:---------------**Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in E:\xampp\htdocs\php4\default.php on line 40.**------The stored procedure in the database receives two input parameters. What's wrong here?

Comment: @pyram SEe change above - you need one bindParam() call per parameter.  If you have additional output params to bind, add a third call for the output.

Comment: Hey im trying to see if the values entered returned a result: `$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(); // Returns the result of the query

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
  
    }`---------But when executing i get: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Comment: @pyram Same problem as before - don't use `mysql_fetch_()`.  Use [PDO fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Having tried Michaels solution for another task and failed miserably with the CALL procedure telling that it expected 0 parameters and got 2, I'll just leave this workaround for others with the same issues:

```
$username_v = $_POST['username'];
$password_v = $_POST['password'];
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';

// You must first connect to the database by instantiating a PDO object
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root_db_pw');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Then you can prepare a statement and execute it.    
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SET @username_v = '$username_v'; SET @password_v = '$password_v';  CALL login()");

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a stored procedure with IN parameter without PDO then below code might help you.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL dataCreation(?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $lastDate);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Hope this will help someone.